# Firing a conversion after set time

Tags: javascript, html

First timer so be gentle :)
I'm trying to fire a conversion after a user spent 6 seconds on my page.
I'm taking a parameter called "clickid" from the URL to identify the conversion.
this is the code I crafted, which is not working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function doGet(e) {
   var params = JSON.stringify(e);
   var clickid = params.parameter.clickid;
    setTimeout(
    function() {
     <iframe src="http://xml.activerevenue.com/conversion?c='+clickid.replace(/\"/g, "")+'" height="1" width="1"></iframe>;    }, 6000); };
</script>
<script> doGet(); </script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you need to run JS inside your function and not put HTML

Comment: what does it mean? can you please paste an example?